# Embed Youtube video link in wordpress editor

Tags: embed, youtube

I have a problem embedding Youtube videos link on my website.The problem is that my website works fine when i post with admin user .. but posting a video with an editor user not working . I copy the embed link, i past it on my wordpress post editor , then when i click post the page refresh and the video disappears from the visual editor and code editor.

P.S : this problem just with Editor users ..

Answer (score 1):

Try just pasting the YouTube URL in to the post or page in the text editor with-out embed code as an editor. See if that works never heard anyone having this problem...

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYmp9HmMYwU&t`

It's super easy to embed videos, images, tweets, audio, and other content into your WordPress site. This feature was added in WordPress 2.9

Go here for a full list of urls that will automatically embed and for what versions of wordpress

https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Comment: Thank you very much .. that solved my problem but i didn't understand how does it work ? why just  pasting the URL solve it ?

Comment: @No signal I updated the answer to explain further but this is a wordpress feature that started at v2.9 and has been added to in further releases be sure to check the complete list in the url I added to the answer and please mark it solved if it helped you